# Conditionally format rows based on a cell value

Tags: excel-2010, conditional-formatting

I have a excel sheet contains data like below.Pno data is based on this formula =Left(B2,1), corresponding numbers displayed in Pno. I'm trying to apply coloring to entire row based on the values in the Pno.

```
Pno EFormat EID
 1  1004    1001
 1  1142    1001
 2  2344    1001
 3  3456    1001
 4  4632    1001
 1  1168    1001
 4  4789    1001
 5  5889    1001
```

If Pno=1 then rows highlited with yellow color, if pno=2 color=blue like that.
I tried rules to format the entire row based on the column A entries

=$A1="1" and pick Yellow
=$A1="2" and pick blue  etc

but color is not hilighting because pno ,Eformat,EID contains formula.
How do i refer conditional formatting.

Comment: You need to define a separate conditional format for each color, or use the color scales option (or you could use some VBA). How many possible values does Pno have?

Comment: Then I would just set a separate conditional formatting formula and color for each condition, e.g., `=A2=2' and then set the color to blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- select A1:C8
- click conditional formatting -> new rule -> use formula to determine which cells to format
- in the formula box type : `=IF(VALUE($A1)=1,TRUE,FALSE)`
- set fill to yellow, click OK

-

- select A1:C8
- click conditional formatting -> new rule -> use formula to determine which cells to format
- in the formula box type : `=IF(VALUE($A1)=2,TRUE,FALSE)`
- set fill to blue, click OK

**EDIT**
Thanks @Doug Glancy for your comment.
The better answer therefore is: (still works the same):

`=VALUE($A1)=1`

Comment: You might be interested in this:http://yoursumbuddy.com/no-ifs-in-conditional-formatting-formulas/